# Allow Glassfish and PHP to work together in the same server using Apache

Tags: java, php, apache

It's possible make a bridge from Java to php file?

I've got an application written in Java and I need execute http://piwik.org/ that is written in PHP. In the server I have PHP running but I cannot access from the browser to the php directory because all incoming traffic is redirected by apache to glassfish Application server.

So my idea is to use Java servlet to execute php files with:

```
Runtime.getRuntime().exec("php /path/to/file/file.php");
```

Then write the PHP output as java servlet response.

The only problems to accomplish this are:

How can I execute PHP cli that act like a browser?

Which parameters I need to pass to PHP to allow PHP to read or write cookie and session?

Comment: If you run the PHP process in CGI mode and se the expected environment variables, PHP should react as though it was executing in say mod_php.  You can reference http://php.net/manual/en/install.unix.commandline.php for details.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you're using Apache anyway to proxy the traffic, I'd just exclude all traffic to Piwik and serve those directly from the file system / `mod_php` / `php-fpm` / whatever you normally use.

You could also use `php-cgi` and pass the appropriate environment variables, but that complicates a lot of stuff, like you'd have to proxy the response back to the browser, too. Apache has already support for this, so don't implement another proxy in your application, do it directly in Apache.

You can exclude a directory from being proxied:

```
ProxyPass /piwik ! 
ProxyPass / 127.0.0.1:8080 
ProxyPassReverse / 127.0.0.1:8080
```

Answer (score 4):

When you execute a php script from the command line the `GET`/`POST`/`SESSION`/`COOKIE`
variables are meaningless. When your `file.php` send a cookie there is no browser to receive it, save it and use it for subsequent requests.

What you can do is use CGI SAPI, so that all `HTTP_*` variables will be usable, and the headers will be written to the output.

The `php-cgi` binary implements the CGI interface, which allows you to pass cookies on the command line like this:

```
HTTP_COOKIE='PHPSESSID=XXXX' php-cgi /path/to/file/file.php
```

Where `XXXX` can be the session id of an user. You can read the cookie analyzing the headers on the output.

Comment: I tried to do that but I receive a warning that alert me I cannot use cookie because the browser not support it. I think i need to set a parameter that allow it.

Comment: Cannot run program "HTTP_COOKIE="test=1"": error=2, No such file or directory 
Now I receive this error only when I execute through Java, using console I receive the output.

Comment: can you try to provide the absolute path of php-cgi? something like `HTTP_COOKIE='PHPSESSID=XXXX' /usr/bin/php-cgi /path/to/file/file.php`

Comment: Yes now I will try. I need to understand first what this do HTTP_COOKIE='PHPSESSID=XXXX' because the Java try to parse as script. probably i need do that in other way with Java.

Comment: it's an environment variable; maybe with `export HTTP_COOKIE='PHPSESSID=XXXX'`?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/101270/discussion-between-andrea-catania-and-federico).

Answer (score 2):

Thanks to the idea of **kelunik** to use Apache to exclude the traffic and the help By **Federico** I've resolved the problem using this Apache rule:

```
ProxyPass /phpdir ! 
ProxyPass / 127.0.0.1:8080 
ProxyPassReverse / 127.0.0.1:8080
```

Apache redirect all request to port 8080, except the folder **/phpdir**. Into the Apache document root I've created the directory **phpdir** that is the new root where the PHP applications will be run.

That's it

Comment: That's the syntax I've been looking for. Edited it into my answer as it's way nicer than with rewrites.